# Why does my simple C++ project terminate in eclipse before I can see it? How do I get this to stop?

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am new to c++, but know a little java so use words I will understand. I am using MinGW.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout <<"C++ is fun!";
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should find plenty: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+console+window+closes

Comment: @555k, Please don't. There are standard ways. Even better, probably a way to make the IDE pause, or the option of running from the command line.

Comment: How would I do the standard way?

Comment: How do I run from the command line?

Comment: Same way you'd run Java from the command line. One command to compile (and link in C++) and another to run. Also, did you bother looking at some questions in the link I posted? I'm sure there are a number of methods discussed.

Comment: What commands would I use like I use javac FirstProgram.java and jar cf FirstProgram.jar

Comment: I think first you can do a RnD stuff to get a better understanding about this basic stuff. Then you can post some valuable questions here.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
system("pause"); // because you want it to pause
```

before

```
return 0;
```